# duplicate entry: android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl.class

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am facing this issue while running my application. I have not updated my android studio and havhe excluded all the support library.
Searched all stackoverflow/github but unable to find the solution
This is my build.gradle file

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile (project(':snaphyandroidsdk')) {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.android.support:design:23.4.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.8-RELEASE') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.9') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.github.techery:ProperRatingBar:ba6de13') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.github.mukeshsolanki:country-picker-android:1.1.6') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.1.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
compile ('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile ('javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Why are you excluding support v4

Comment: @ManojFrekzz everyone is other answers are telling to remove it, so I tried same but with no results

Comment: Instead of that try by deleting the support library v4 from external libraries.

Comment: @ManojFrekzz I don't know how to do that..Can you provide me an example?

Comment: @Ravi do u have any jars in lib folder?

Comment: No, I have no jar files